# Fourier transformation of two separated spheres

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I would like to fourier transform two spheres with radius $r_1$ and $r_2$ and distance d where d is larger than $r_1$ + $r_2$.

The fourier transformation of one sphere is well known as:
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2-y^2}}e^{iq\cdot r}dxdydz $$

How can I add the second spheres to this integral.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the speed at which a Fourier series converges is improved by the differentiability of a function, even certain distributions such as the Dirac delta distribution will admit Fourier transforms without being functions (let alone continuous functions). A similar principal applies to Fourier transforms.

In short, to take the Fourier transform of a function on two disjoint balls, multiply your function the characteristic function of their set in three dimensional space. Then simply take the Fourier transform over all of three dimensional space.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   f(x) \chi_{B} e^{-ikr} dx dy dz
$$

where $r$ is a three dimensional vector and $\chi_B$ is the characteristic function that is only nonzero on the two disjoint balls.

For further reading, I would recommend researching partitions of unity.

Note that the final integral can be done in whatever coordinates you wish. You could integrate over each sphere and sum them together to get the Fourier transform for a function over both of them. In a sense, the each sphere is mutually unaware of the function defined on the other. You only need to superpose them by addition and linearity of the integral.

Sorry if there are any typos, I wrote this on my phone.

**Edit:** I just realized you posted a similar question to StackOverflow stating that you wished you knew the characteristic function between two spheres. You can define it simply as

$$
\chi_B = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } ||\vec{x} - \vec{c}_1|| \leq r_1 \text{ or } ||\vec{x} - \vec{c}_2|| \leq r_2  \\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
where $\vec{c}_1$ and $\vec{c}_2$ are the centers of the first and second spheres and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are their radii. In fact, this characteristic function will generalize to any arbitrary metric space be replacing $||\vec{x}-\vec{y}||$ with $d(x, y)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer. I thought I overlook something by integrating over each sphere and adding them together. 

I wonder that the result is then independent of the distance d between two spheres. Can you please briefly discuss the distance dependence of the result?

Comment: Yes, the result will depend on the distance between the balls if the _original function_ $f(x)$ depends on the distance between the balls. (I call them balls as a sphere is only the _surface_ of a ball. If we were examining spheres, we would use a two dimensional surface integral. The integral you provided was a three dimensional volume integral, so we are really trying to compute the Fourier transform of a function over the two balls.) Further, we may also note that the characteristic function $\chi_B$ is independent of the distance between the balls. By this independence, I mean that the...

Comment: local structure of $\chi_B$ is the same wherever we define in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $f(x)$ does depend on the distance between the two balls, I recommend looking for a certain symmetry between the balls as a means of simplifying the integral. Without knowing an explicit formula for $f(x)$, I cannot be of any more help as there is no symmetry in the general case. I recommend looking up a section in measure theory, Rudin's undergraduate analysis has a nice chapter on the subject. Please upvote my answer if you found it helpful, thanks.